# Creating Data Model in Excel using VBA getting Query Not Found

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of tables (UserForm listbox) I want my users to pull into Excel when they need to create a PowerPivot.  I create the query just fine, I am then trying to create the connection, but I am getting an error that the query does not exist. I know it does because I just created it.

Here is the code.  I have attached a screenshot of the error I am getting.
[image]

```
Dim myServer As String
Dim myDatabase As String
Dim myTable As String
Dim mySchema As String
Dim myQueryName
Dim myQuery As WorkbookQuery
Dim x

For x = 0 To Me.lstSupplementalTables.ListCount - 1
     If Me.lstSupplementalTables.Selected(x) Then
          mySchema = Me.lstSupplementalTables.List(x, 0)
          myTable = Me.lstSupplementalTables.List(x, 1)
          myQueryName = mySchema & "_" & myTable
                   
'QUERY
     Set myQuery = ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add(mySchema & "_" & myTable, _
          "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Sql.Database(""" & myServer & """, """ & myDatabase & """)," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    " & mySchema & "_" & myTable & " = Source{[Schema=""" & mySchema & """,Item=""" & myTable & """]}[Data]" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    " & mySchema & "_" & myTable)

Call RefreshQueries  '<---- I just added this No queries are found even though the line above creates one

'CREATE DATA MODEL CONNECTION  *******  THIS IS WHERE I AM GETTING THAT THE QUERY DOES NOT EXISTS
     ThisWorkbook.Connections.Add2 "Query - " & myQuery.Name, _
          "Connection to the '" & myQuery.Name & " ' query in the workbook.", _
          "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=" & myQuery.Name _
          , """" & myQuery.Name & """", 6, True, False
```

I have changed my code many times, but what I have above seems to be what I keep finding as the solution, but it is not working when I try and make the connection.

I found this code and added it to refresh the Queries but it is not finding any queries.  So even though I see I have a Query and it is a connection only Excel does not think I have one.

```
Public Sub RefreshQueries()

  Dim wks As Worksheet
  Dim qt As PivotTable
  Dim lo As ListObject

  For Each wks In Worksheets
    For Each qt In wks.QueryTables
        qt.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    Next qt

    For Each lo In wks.ListObjects
        lo.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    Next lo

  Next wks

  Set qt = Nothing
  Set wks = Nothing
End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Rodger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out my issue.  It was a simple error on my part.  When trying to create the connection I was using `ThisWorkbook.Connections.Add2` and it should be  `ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Add2` Once I made that change my functions work as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the query is fully created or fully loaded usually this kind of error pops in the above cases. Or else you can try the refresh method.

Comment: I did have a refresh before trying to add the connection.  Using ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll but that did not help.  I am using myQuery.Name which does have the name of the query so I think it is being created.  How else could I tell? Any help would be grateful.